# What does "with some flowers" modify in this sentence?

Tags: sentence-construction

I plant the garden **with some flowers**.

Is it the same as "I plant some flowers in the garden."? What are their nuances?

What does "with some flowers" modify in this sentence?

Answer (score 1):

The sentences mean the same.

However, *to plant the garden with some flowers* is ambiguous. You could interpret *some flowers* as the tool with which you are planting something.

This phrase is much clearer and not ambiguous:

> plant some flowers in the garden

Answer (score 0):

"With some flowers" is not a modifier, it's a complement of the verb "plant".  It's the logical direct object.  Why is there a "with"?  Who knows?  It is probably like the "with" that turns up before the logical direct object in some indirect object constructions: "He presented a gift to her" = "He presented her with a gift".

Answer (score 0):

I would see "with some flowers" as a second object that simply indicates with what as in: I fill the bowl with water.